# Matplotlib set_data xdata and ydata must be same length error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a simple `matplotlib`chart that I would like to add points to via a function. It seems that when I extend the arrays the store x and y values, I get the error `RuntimeError: xdata and ydata must be the same length` despite both arrays being 6 values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([1, 7, 5])

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax.plot(x, y, 'r-')
plt.show()


def update_points(new_x, new_y):
    global x, y, fig, line1, ax
    time.sleep(2)
    x = np.append(x, new_x)
    y = np.append(y, new_y)
    line1.set_xdata(x)
    line1.set_xdata(y)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    fig.canvas.draw()


update_points(np.array([4, 5, 6]), np.array([4, 5, 3]))
```

Comment: You have a typo: `line1.set_xdata(y)` should be `line1.set_ydata(y)` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is so because you've very initially creates a graph already with reference variable `line1`. Therefore, when you execute the function that you've created, for the first time say, you already have a plot and therefore it becomes erroneous to just change one axis at a time

So this is wrong

`line1.set_xdata(x)
 line1.set_xdata(y)`

Change it to

`line1.set_data(x,y)`

If you've already drawn the plot, do a redraw using `plt.draw()` to see the change.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but it seems like it still needs to be `fig.canvas.draw()` rather than `plt.draw()`

Comment: Yes, because here, you are drawing it for the first time. I said 'if' you'd have had already drawn it, you would want to redraw and so that command.

Comment: got it, so if I call that multiple times, is there a way to check if the plot has already been drawn and call `plt.draw()` instead of the second call?

Comment: Why would you wanna check? Just do a plt.draw() or fig.canvas.draw() to see the change. Both perform equally.

Comment: ok, I thought maybe plt.draw() was preferable with still with fig.canvas.draw()

Comment: I am not very sure about the differences but please do check for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone who is still landing on this, there are two solutions to this problem.

The first solution is what [Aakash Verma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5924738/aakash-verma) wrote [in their solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872809/12131013), which is to replace `line1.set_xdata(x)` and `line1.set_xdata(y)` with simply `line1.set_data(x,y)`, which will keep the `xdata` and `ydata` the same lengths, assuming inputs x and y are the same lengths.

The second solution is to notice that [user2242044](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2242044/user2242044) simply made a typo and twice wrote `set_xdata` when the second time it should have been `set_ydata`. This is what is causing the `RuntimeError: xdata and ydata must be the same length` (or, for me with Python 3, `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`), because twice the program is adding to the `xdata` while there is no matching `ydata` to plot.